# jQuery DataTables with Bootstrap Styling and responsive extension does't work

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, datatables

In my html page i replaced the example of this [link](http://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap.html). In the head tag i have this:

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http:////cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/a5734b29083/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.1/css/dataTables.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

for the css and this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http:////cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http:////cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/a5734b29083/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
```

for the javascript.

The table is this:

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First name</th>
                    <th>Last name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Extn.</th>
                    <th>E-mail</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quinn</td>
                    <td>Flynn</td>
                    <td>Support Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2013/03/03</td>
                    <td>$342,000</td>
                    <td>9497</td>
                    <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quinn</td>
                    <td>Flynn</td>
                    <td>Support Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2013/03/03</td>
                    <td>$342,000</td>
                    <td>9497</td>
                    <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quinn</td>
                    <td>Flynn</td>
                    <td>Support Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2013/03/03</td>
                    <td>$342,000</td>
                    <td>9497</td>
                    <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I call datatable at the end of body with:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable({
                responsive: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```

My code seems the same of the example on the DataTable site. It works and my doesn't work. Why?

Comment: And you have called the function?

Comment: You called the function to create the table? Like: `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );`

Comment: Try moving the scripts to the end of the `<body>`

Comment: done. it still doesn't work

Comment: @user3083618 Did you find a fix for this? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is collapsing not working ? What is the issue you are getting. Any console error ? 
I have copied the same code as you have mentioned above and created a fiddle example. You can check it here ?[Fiddle Example for Responsive DataTable](http://jsfiddle.net/YameenYasin/ysu6o79t/7/)
Hope this helps .

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-hover dt-responsive" cellspacing="0" width="90%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First name</th>
                    <th>Last name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Extn.</th>
                    <th>E-mail</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quinn</td>
                    <td>Flynn</td>
                    <td>Support Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2013/03/03</td>
                    <td>$342,000</td>
                    <td>9497</td>
                    <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quinn</td>
                    <td>Flynn</td>
                    <td>Support Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2013/03/03</td>
                    <td>$342,000</td>
                    <td>9497</td>
                    <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Quinn</td>
                    <td>Flynn</td>
                    <td>Support Lead</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2013/03/03</td>
                    <td>$342,000</td>
                    <td>9497</td>
                    <td>q.flynn@datatables.net</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body { font-size: 140% 
}
.row{
        border:1px solid black;
}     
table.dataTable th,
table.dataTable td {
        white-space: nowrap;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's too many `//` symbols in your css & js lines. The second css link has:

```
link href="http:////cdn.datatables......
```

and it should be:

```
link href="http://cdn.datatables......
```

The second and third script calls have the same issue, too.

Answer (score 0):

Premise: I'm writing this reply because I'm facing the same problem and since I don't find a good example/tutorial, I explain how I'll deal with this.

---

I suggest to look at the source code in the DataTables Bootstrap Styling page

[DataTables Bootstrap Styling](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap.html)

That page shows DataTables and the Responsive extension being used with the Bootstrap framework providing the styling

Said first that below the demo table being shown in the DataTables Bootstrap Styling, there are the correct CSS, JS and HTML to be used for the case, and if am I not wrong, they are also placed in the correct order,

you have another option to go for:

just watch at the source code of that page, e.g. in Firefox I press Ctrl-u and in the address bar it is opened

`view-source:https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap.html`

this allows to see the source code of the rendered html.

Find the same command for your browser and you'll see how at DataTables website they setup the CSS(es) and JS(es) scripts to make it working.

What looks sharp is that they just use this script to initialize the table

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

so no `responsive` keyword is used,

which makes it bright that the magic looks done by the singles CSS and JS (if correctly loaded).

In the end, to start from a safe point, place the js scripts loading in the HEAD section of your html test page and begin with making this to succesfully work,

only after a positive test, if needed, move them where you want.

Answer (score -1):

Ha!  I had this very same problem.

```
    <link href="http://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.1/css/dataTables.responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Is referencing the wrong CSS file, which is:

```
responsive.dataTables.css
```

And why is the naming convention for the stylesheets different from the naming convention for the javascript files?  Dunno!